# `Maximize` is running forever

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to maximize the following function $f$ with respect to $r$ and $k$:

$f=\frac{d^3+3 d^2 (k (r-1)-s)+3 d \left(k^2 ((r-3) r+1)+2 k r s-2 (r-1) s^2\right)+k^3 (r ((r-1) r+3)-1)-3 k^2 r^2 s+3 (r-1) s^3}{6 (r-1) s^2}$

under the conditions of $0<d<1,2d<s,d\leq k\leq s, 0\leq r \leq \frac{d}{k} $.

My Mathematica code is:

```
Maximize[{1/(6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)), 0 < d < 1, 2 d < s, d <= k <= s, 0<=r<= d/k}, {r, k}]
```

And it is running forever. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try $s=1,2,\frac 1 3,\dots$

Comment: s = 1/3; Maximize[{.
      }, {r, k}] // 
  ToRadicals // TeXForm performs $$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{18} \left(-27 d^3+54 d^2-27 d+4\right) & 0<d<\frac{1}{6} \\
 -\infty  & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{r\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0<d<\frac{1}{6} \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,k\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} & 0<d<\frac{1}{6} \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: s=2 and the above command performs $$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{24} \left(-d^3+12 d^2-36 d+32\right) & 0<d<1 \\
 -\infty  & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{r\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0<d<1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,k\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0<d<1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: Thanks, user64494. Do you know we can solve this without assigning a specific value to s? Why wouldn't Mathematica solve my original code?

Comment: No, I don't know it. My experiment suggests that  the (finite) optimal solution is reached at $r=0,k=s$. I think Mma has problems with a complex nonlinear target function and a nonlinear constraint and two parameters. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find the maxima is to calculate the derivatives and set them equal to zero. Here f[ ] is your function:

```
f[r_, k_] := 
  1/(6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 
     3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 
     3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2));
dfdr = D[f[r, k], r];
dfdk = D[f[r, k], k];
Solve[dfdr == 0 && dfdk == 0 && 0 < d < 1 && 2 d < s && d <= k <= s &&
   0 <= r <= d/k, {r, k}]
```

This seems to work, and gives a fairly long set of ConditionalExpressions in terms of Root objects. You should probably also check that the solution is a max and not a min or saddle point.