# 3D Plot maximization results with varying parameter values

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to maximize the following objective function with respect to $r$ and $k$

$objF = \frac{d^3+3 d^2 (k (r-1)-s)+3 d \left(k^2 ((r-3) r+1)+2 k r s-2 (r-1) s^2\right)+k^3 (r ((r-1) r+3)-1)-3 k^2 r^2 s+3 (r-1) s^3}{6 (r-1) s^2}$

under the conditions of $0\leq d\leq 1$, $s\geq 2 d$, $d\leq k\leq s$, and $0\leq r<\frac{d}{k}$. And plot the maximum of the objective function, $r^*$, and $k^*$ against the varying parameter values of $d \in [0,1]$ and $s\in [0,2]$.

My Mathematica code is:

```
Block[{t = 0}, objF = 1/( 6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)); max = Flatten[Table[{d, s, MaxValue[{objF, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxk = Flatten[Table[{d, s, k /. Last@Maximize[{objF, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxr = Flatten[Table[{d, s, r /. Last@Maximize[{objF, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1];] {ListPlot3D[max, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "objF"}], ListPlot3D[maxk, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "k"}], ListPlot3D[maxr, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "r"}]}
```

And I got the following result.

[image]

I have two issues (or questions) with this result.

First, I'm curious what the gray areas in the last diagram mean.

Second, in order to check the concrete value of the objective function with specific parameter values, e.g., $s=1.8$ and $d=0.7$, I used the following code:

```
Block[{s = 1.8, d = 0.7}, objF = 1/( 6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)); max = MaxValue[{objF, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]; maxk = k /. Last@Maximize[{objF, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]; maxr = r /. Last@Maximize[{objF, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]] {max, maxk, maxr}
```

And the result is:

[image]

That is, the maximum $objF=0$, $k^* =0$, and $r^* =0$. This result is very strange since a quick inspection of the above diagrams show that at $s=1.8$ and $d=0.7$, we have both the maximum $objF$ and $k^*$ positive.

Comment: How is this different from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201660/1783 and what is wrong with the answer there? Your code here does not maximize the objective function.

Comment: Since the analytical solution turns out to be very complicated with a lot of conditional expression with `Root[#]`, I am trying a numerical solution by simulation. Thanks for your help, Bill!

Comment: Hi Bill, shall I merge the two posts into one or delete the previous post? I would really appreciate if anyone could help me on this post. Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the analytical solution and plot that for specific values (rather than trying to redo the maximization). You'll need to learn to use root objects (see help for Root). They're not really that hard!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, bill s. As you already know, the analytical solution turns out to be very complicated (its expression covers more than one entire page). Do you think it is still something manageable? If I can get an analytical solution as you suggest, then there is actually no need to do the numerical simulation.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I tried your suggestion, i.e. `Simplify[...]`, but got exactly the same result. On the other hand, the analytical solution, for example, the second solution of $r$ consisting of more than 10 `Root[]`'s, looks daunting! Do you think interpreting it is possible? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of your first question is quite easy: You try to plot a value which is near zero and cut the negativ part (PlotRange).

I'm wondering why you didn't use `NMaximize`? Here my approach(firstly without restriction `0<d<1, d <= s/2`)

```
max[d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := {d, s,NMaximize[{1/(6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 +k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 3 d (k^2 (1+ (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)), 
d <= k <= s, 0 <= r k < d}, {k, r}]}
```

That's it.

Plot the results (requires some time...)

```
ListPlot3D[DeleteCases[Table[{d, s, r /. max[d, s][[3, 2]]}, {d, 0.05, 1, .05}, {s, 2 d, 1, .05}], {}] // Flatten[#, 1] &, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {d, s, r}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[DeleteCases[Table[{d, s, k /. max[d, s][[3, 2]]}, {d, 0.05, 1, .05}, {s, 2 d, 1, .05}], {}] // Flatten[#, 1] &, AxesLabel -> {d, s, k}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[DeleteCases[Table[{d, s, max[d, s][[3, 1]]}, {d, 0.05, 1, .05}, {s, 2 d, 1, .05}], {}] // Flatten[#, 1] &, AxesLabel -> {d, s, max}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich! May I ask you a question? I tried the simulation without the condition $s > 2d$. And also, tried to do the `Plot3D` with the range of both $d$ and $s$ starting from 0. Accordingly, the parameter value range in the code would be: {d, 0, 1, .05}, {s, 0, 2, .05}. When run, I get a list of error messages; one of them is "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered". Do you know why? Can you please help me once more? I really appreciate!

Comment: As for the range of parameter values in `Plot3D`, I also tried many different variations. For example,  {d, 0.01, 1, .05}, {s, 0.01, 2, .05} or {d, 0.05, 1, .05}, {s, d, 2, .05}. All these generate the similar error messages.

Comment: With `d=0` I also got problems, that's why I started with small d. `Plot3D`  simulated very long time.

Comment: Hi Ulich, may I ask you one more question? When I use `PlotRange -> {0,1}` for $r$ in the first diagram, I get basically the same result, but the area is in gray, not in orange. Do you know why?

Comment: Try a small lower limit in the plotrange.